# SQL Server - Find Missing Numbers in sequence where numbers contain preceding zeros

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, gaps-and-islands

I have numbers in sequence stored in database which are stored as text and contain preceding zeros.

```
Numbers
-------
001
002
003
004
006
007
010
011
-------
```

The query should find following result

```
Missing
-------
005
008
009
-------
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is the range of numbers you have? How are numbers greater than 100 stored?

Comment: Greater than 100 numbers are stored as 100,101 etc and maximum numbers is 9999

Comment: Have you tried put your question title into search engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a sequence of number table ( there are so many implementations already in SO) and then use `LEFT JOIN`. See below query:  `seq` is sequence of number form 1 to 9999 as `int`.

```
;with seq as 
(
select top 9999 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
from   master..spt_values t1 
       cross join master..spt_values t2

)

SELECT RIGHT('000'+CAST(s.n AS VARCHAR(3)),3) as MissingNumbers
from seq s 
left join yourtable t on s.n = cast(t.Number as int)
where t.number is null
```